# How to resolve Visual Studio's Unrecognized namespace warnings?

Tags: facebook, visual-studio-2012, facebook-javascript-sdk, xml-namespaces

The screenshot says it all.  How does one resolve such warnings?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your master page use fb xmlns like  this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```